# Error Even after Explicit Instatantiation

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to get a template code working with the header file and cpp file separated. I use explicit instantiation for this. But I still get an undefined reference error.

foo.h

```
template<typename T>
class Foo 
{
 public:
  void f();
};
```

foo.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Foo.h"

template<typename T>
void Foo<T>::f() 
{
 std::cout << "Foo<T>::f()\n"; 
}

template class Foo<int>;
```

main.cc

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
 Foo<int> x;
 x.f();
}
```

When I compile:

```
g++ main.cc -o test
/tmp/ccfHjiVJ.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `Foo<int>::f()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The gcc version I use is gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC)

Comment: Possibly it was a bug in this version of gcc. This code is standard-compliant and compiles in newer versions of gcc.

Comment: Indeed, works for me in GCC 4.7, and I don't have any older version handy. 4.4 is a bit oldschool now. Does puttting `template class Foo<int>;` in the header file help at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to compile `foo.cc` in your compile command, add `foo.cc`:

```
g++ main.cc foo.cc -o test
            ^^^^^^
```